# Is there an option to use postprocessor in nesting translations in i18next?

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I use i18next for localization. I am using a postprocessor that applies custom format. I have recently noticed that in nested translations this postprocessor is not applied. Is there something I can do to have it applied in nested translations?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the specific use-case?

Comment: @felixmosh, imagine that I am not using built-in plurals handling. Besides that I use formatter (plurr https://github.com/loctools/plurr) which I call in postprocessor. And I write something like that in the translation: `"files": {N {file|files}} in directory"` instead of two keys `files` and `files_plural`. So I am trying to use this key as a nested translation - `You have $t(files, {'N': '{{filesCount'}}})`. I get the exact key value as a translation - `{N {file|files}} in directory` and my postprocessor has not being called (I also checked it via debugger).

Comment: I'm not familiar plurr. can you add a codesandbox with a working example?
You can fork this, https://codesandbox.io/s/8187wm9yj8

Comment: @felixmosh, sure. I already was making one.

Comment: But it not working :]... just add the relevant code please

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-sun-7kc7f?file=/src/app.js

Comment: @felixmosh, yeah, I did not save it properly. sorry... Now it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've debugged the code of i18next, and found out that for nested translations post-processors are [disabled by default](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/b8b014f99a16af73f458c32f167e485447d76f92/src/Interpolator.js#L153).

You can enable this flag inside the translation:

```
// translations.json
nested: "You have $t(files, {'N': 10, 'applyPostProcessor': true})"
// ------------------------------------------^
```

A working example :]

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cloud-pz6yz?file=/src/app.js